# Get signal quality in % from iwconfig

Tags: awk

first post for help....
I am trying to get signal quality in % from the iwconfig command...
I began with this command but it returns the text 'signal value'

```
iwconfig wlan0 | grep Quality | awk -F '=|/|=[  ]' '{print $2,$3}'

70 70  Signal level
```

I'd like just want to have '100%' as a result

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"SKYNET"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: AC:84:C9:CD:79:E0
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:51  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: please add the output of `iwconfig wlan0` in your question for further help

Answer (score 1):

Following is doing (68/70)*100. using `split()`  68 is stored in `a[2]` whereas 70 is stored in `a[3]`

```
iwconfig wlan0|awk '/Link Quality/{split($2,a,"=|/");print (a[2]/a[3])*100"%"}'
97.1429%
```

for integer result:

```
iwconfig wlan0|awk '/Link Quality/{split($2,a,"=|/");print int((a[2]/a[3])*100)"%"}'
97%
```

or just use `printf`:

```
iwconfig wlan0|awk '/Link Quality/{split($2,a,"=|/");printf "%d%s\n", (a[2]/a[3])*100, "%"}'
97%
```

PS: Tested with the output supplied by OP in question.

Comment: Yes, great, thanks a lot... last question, how to get an integer as a result ?

Comment: you can use `int()` like `print int((a[2]/a[3])*100)"%"`